# passing value from request in function to other function in same controller

Tags: laravel-8

I would like in My ContactController.php (which manages my US contact) replace the recipient's email address with a value get from the database in a table called Student ..

'''
<?php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use App\Models\Student;
use App\Models\ContactUs;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactController extends Controller
{

    public function showForm(Request $request)
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }


    public function Infos(Request $request)
    {
        $info = Student::find(1)->value('monemail');

        //// do something

        
    }

    public function storeForm(Request $request)
    {

        ///get value of $info 

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'subject' => 'required|max:100',
            'message' => 'required|max:400'
        ]);

        ContactUs::create($request->all());

        \Mail::send('email', array(
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
            'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
            'form_message' => $request->get('message'),
        ), function ($message) use ($request) {
            
            $message->from($request->email);

            //change test@test.fr by value of $info in Infos method

            $message->to('test@test.fr', 'Message de Transport Parisien')->subject($request->get('subject'));
        });

        return back()->with('success', 'Thank.');
    }
}
```

'''

I do not remember how to pass the value of a result to another method in the same controller

Thank for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found that as a solution. It's working. If someone has another solution can be more elegant.

'''

```
function ($message) use ($request) {
            $info = Student::find(1)->value('monemail');
            $message->from($request->email);
            $message->to($info, 'Message from me')->subject($request->get('subject'));
```

'''
Have a good day.